# Pihole + Unbound in Docker Container

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4, unbound, pihole

I have a raspberry pi 4 with ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l). I have been trying for days to find a solution to have pihole and unbound with DNS over TLS in docker containers.

Since I do not have much experience in dockers (please be lenient) I found [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/juampe/pihole-dot) which I pulled like this `docker pull juampe/pihole-dot` (I am not sure if I should pull the digest of linux/arm/v7 or how could I do that).

This image has this example run-command:

> docker run --init -d --restart=always --network=eraser --dns 127.0.0.1
> --ip 192.168.0.2 -e ServerIP="192.168.0.2" --hostname pihole -e VIRTUAL_HOST="pihole" --name="pihole" -e "WEBPASSWORD=admin" -e
> "TZ=Europe/Madrid" -e "DOT_UPSTREAM=1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1" -e
> "DNS1=127.0.0.1#5353" -e "DNS2=no" --cap-add=NET_ADMIN
> --cap-add=SYS_NICE -v /opt/docker/pihole/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d/ -v /opt/docker/pihole/pihole:/etc/pihole juampe/pihole-dot

Well, I created a docker network called eraser (without configuring it, I do not know if it needs configuration) and then I replaced the IPs from the following argument

> --ip 192.168.0.2 ServerIP = "192.168.0.2"

with raspberry's IP.

The following warning appeared when I executed the command:

> WARNING: Localhost DNS setting (--dns = 127.0.0.1) may fail in
> containers.

However, the container got up normally.
The output of the `docker container ls` command is shown below

```
1bb81122e7cb
juampe
pihole-dot
s6-init
14 hours ago Up About a minute (health: starting)
53/udp
53/tcp
80/tcp
67/udp
pihole
```

From the above output I understood that port 80 had been exposed and so I tried to open the url `http://localhost` and the url `http://<Raspberry's_Local_IP>`. Unfortunately both were unreachable.

So, since no error occurs I would greatly appreciate if you could explain to me what is wrong or even if you could give me just a command that worked on your raspberry or VM (and through it I will find out what I did wrong, since I am a docker-noob but not super-noob).

Thank you in advance!